# Compare enum values in JSP

Tags: java, spring, enums, jstl

I've created an `enum` which looks like:

```
public enum BtsMode {
    PROJECT_BTS("project_bts"), SERVICE_BTS("service_bts");

    private String mode;

    private BtsMode(String mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public String getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

    public static BtsMode getBtsMode(Integer projectId) {
        return projectId == 0 ? BtsMode.SERVICE_BTS : BtsMode.PROJECT_BTS;
    }
};
```

This enum is a part of a class which contains other application level constants.
Based on the `projectId` value, I do other operations in my `Spring/java` application. On the UI side, I wish to use the same `enum` to compare the `BtsMode` type and do operations. I have searched the net and found that I can iterate over the `enum` and compare, but I have to check the specific `BtsMode` type.

Using the `getBtsMode()` method, I get the appropriate `BtsMode` and set it to the Spring `ModelMap` attribute.

```
BtsMode btsMode = BtsMode.getBtsMode(projectId);
modelMap.addAttribute("curBtsMode", btsMode);
```

In the JSP, I want to show hide the content depending on the `BtsMode`. Something like this,

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${curBtsMode eq BtsMode.PROJECT_BTS}">
        <%-- Display elements specific to PROJECT_BTS --%>          
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${curBtsMode eq BtsMode.SERVICE_BTS}">
        <%-- Display elements specific to SERVICE_BTS --%>          
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

I do not want to use scriptlets because we don't use them in our application. Is there any other way to achieve this?

**Temporary Solution**

Currently, as BtsMode enum having only two values, I can use it by setting in modelMap:

```
modelMap.addAttribute("projBtsMode", BtsMode.PROJECT_BTS);
modelMap.addAttribute("serviceBtsMode", BtsMode.SERVICE_BTS);
```

And accessing in JSP:

```
<c:if test="${curBtsMode eq projBtsMode}">
```

This works fine, but if there is any better solution, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you are using at least version 3.0 of EL, then you can import constants into your page as follows:

```
<%@ page import="org.example.Status" %>
<c:when test="${dp.status eq Status.VALID}">
```

Some IDE dont understand this,so use alternative.

Helper Methods

```
  public enum Status { 
  VALID("valid")

  private final String val;

  Status(String val) {
    this.val = val;
  }

  public String getStatus() {
    return val;
  }

  public boolean isValid() {
    return this == VALID;
  }

}
```

JSP:

```
<c:when test="${dp.status.valid}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with a simple String:

```
<c:when test="${curBtsMode  == 'PROJECT_BTS'}">
    <%-- Display elements specific to PROJECT_BTS --%>          
</c:when>
<c:when test="${curBtsMode == 'SERVICE_BTS'}">
    <%-- Display elements specific to SERVICE_BTS --%>          
</c:when>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I thought of it as the first choice and it works but I think it beats the purpose of using the constants or enum. But though it can solve the problem I will upvote, still feel there could be a better solution. Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, I admit my current answer it's a bit against enum logic. I usually use a little scriplet (like <c:set var="PROJECT_BTS" value="<%=BtsMode.PROJECT_BTS%>"/> <c:when test="${curBtsMode == PROJECT_BTS}">) to circumvent the issue. A little scriplet like this won't hurt (too much :) )